# directive with transclude:true, how to access parent scope variable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

this is my code,

```
theModule.directive('someVideo', [ function(){

    function link(scope, element, attrs, parentCtrl) {
        var htmlVideo = angular.element(element).find('video')[0];
        var htmlCanvas = angular.element(element).find('canvas')[0];
        scope.$watch('video.src', function(n,o){
            console.log(n,'video.src');
            htmlVideo.src = n;
            htmlVideo.play();            
        });

    };  

    return {
        transclude: true,
        link: link,
        templateUrl: 'partials/someVideo.html'
    };
}]);
```

partials/someVideo.html

```
<video autoplay="true" crossOrigin=''  ng-class="video.id" >    </video>
```

homepage.html

```
            <div someVideo />
```

For this block, I am monitering if `video.src` attribute has changed( in controller) and html5video element is reloaded and plays the new source, that part works fine, but how do I access the `video` variable( present in my controller) in this directive?

Answer (score 0):

```
  scope: false
  transclude: false
```

and you will have the same scope(with parent element)

```
$scope.$watch(...
```

There are a lot of ways how to access parent scope depending on this two options scope& transclude.

Comment: tried your answer, was getting the same output, then I realized my mistake, I was using ```video``` instead of ```scope.video```.